# jQuery Ajax Request with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am producing multiple forms from my php code as shown below.

The problem is that, If I want to perform a jquery-ajax request, How can I refer to a form. My goal is that when the submit button is clicked, the relevant data from that form should be posted.

Previously, I was referring to form with its `$('#id').submit()` function. But I am stuck here since all of the forms have the same name.

```
<form id="view-doc" method="post" target="report" action="../classes/openDoc.php">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="Research Writer Test 8.doc" />
<input type="hidden" id="filetype" name="filetype" value="doc" />
<td><input type="submit" class="s-button btn_normal" id="submit" value="View" onsubmit="window.open(about:blank,report,width=300,height=200)" />
</form>

<form id="view-doc" method="post" target="report" action="../classes/openDoc.php">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="template[1].IEEEdoc.doc" />
<input type="hidden" id="filetype" name="filetype" value="doc" />
<input type="submit" class="s-button btn_normal" id="submit" value="View" onsubmit="window.open(about:blank,report,width=300,height=200)" />
</form>

<form id="view-doc" method="post" target="report" action="../classes/openDoc.php">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="Assignment #3.docx" />
<input type="hidden" id="filetype" name="filetype" value="ocx" />
<input type="submit" class="s-button btn_normal" id="submit" value="View" onsubmit="window.open(about:blank,report,width=300,height=200)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attribute has to be unique. If possible please consider `view-doc-1`, `view-doc-2` and `view-doc-3` for the forms' `id`.

Otherwise, use `class` instead of `id` and do this on JavaScript:

```
$(".view-doc input[type=submit]".bind('click', function() {
   // your code when button clicked. fired on all the 3 buttons
});
```

Comment: This will execute only the submit button you click on!

Comment: Thanks, by the way can we use same names but different id's?. for example view-doc-1 and view-doc-2 will have same name (view-doc) but different id's. Perhaps I can use like this.